# Why does halting trading of the ERUS ETF (Russia-focused ETF) protect the best interests of ERUS shareholders?

Tags: trading, stock-markets, etf

I read on https://www.marketwatch.com/amp/story/nyse-halts-trading-in-ishares-msci-russia-etf-blackrock-supports-decision-2022-03-04 ([mirror](https://archive.ph/Nul0H)):

> ​Trading in the [iShares MSCI Russia ETF ERUS](https://www.google.com/search?q=erus+stock) has been halted by NYSE Arca, as of 4 a.m. Eastern time on Friday. The ETF (ERUS) tumbled 25.5% on Thursday to a record-low close of $8.06, following MSCI Inc.'s MSCI announcement that Russia's equity markets were uninvestable, and has plummeted 72.8% since Russia's invasion of Ukraine started on Feb. 24. "Due to ERUS' concentrated exposure to Russian equities, the closure of the Russian stock market and MSCI's decision to remove Russian securities from its Emerging Markets Indexes, BlackRock strongly supports NYSE Arca's decision and is **committed to protecting the best interests of ERUS shareholders**," said BlackRock Inc. BLK , which manages the ETF, in a statement."

Why does halting trading of the ERUS ETF protect the best interests of ERUS shareholders?

My thought was that regardless its price evolution, stopping the trading for some time won't change it's value whenever it starts trading again.

Comment: '*stopping the trading for some time won't change it's value whenever it starts trading again*' - citation needed

Comment: @littleadv citation: Franck's thought. Perhaps incorrect. Hence this question.